# What determines whether numpy returns NAN or INF upon divide-by-zero

Tags: python, numpy

Im trying to understand the following results:

```py
In [1]: with np.errstate(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore'):
    ...:     for val in 1e-324,2e-324,3e-324:
    ...:         val_by_zero = np.array([val])/0
    ...:         print( val_by_zero, np.nan_to_num(val_by_zero))
    ...:
    ...:
[nan] [0.]
[nan] [0.]
[inf] [1.79769313e+308]


In [2]: np.__version__
Out[2]: '1.20.3'

In [3]: np.finfo(np.float64)
Out[3]: finfo(resolution=1e-15, min=-1.7976931348623157e+308, max=1.7976931348623157e+308, dtype=float64)
```

I am just curious exactly whats going on in within the numpy library that determines whether a float is inf or nan.

This is python 3.8.12 running on CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009.

NOTE: I arrived at the numbers `vals=[1e-324, 2e-324, 3e-324]` after inspecting an application that was corrupted by unwanted large numbers (e.g. the float max `1.79769313e+308`). I imagine that these `vals` are platform and/or configuration dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first positive number that can be represented by `float64` is `5e-324`.

```
from numpy import nextafter
# Starting from 0 and going towards 1, what is the next representable value?
nextafter(0, 1, dtype='float64')
# Out: 5e-324
```

`1e-324` and `2e-324` are closer to 0 so they are represented as 0 but `3e-324` is closer to `5e-324` so it is represented as `5e-324`.

```
from numpy import array
array([1e-324, 2e-324, 3e-324], dtype='float64')
# Out: array([0.e+000, 0.e+000, 5.e-324])
```

At this point it boils down to `positive number / 0` vs `0 / 0`. The former is infinity while the latter is undefined.

Comment: Wonderfully explained! Thanks